# pics first argument behavior different in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462209/positioning-elements-in-a-scope/462310#462310) question and try to modify it as below:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,fit,calc}  
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{cross}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
    \foreach \i in {center,north,south,east,west} {
        \inheritanchor[from=circle]{\i}
    }
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\radius}%
    }
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{-135}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{45}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{135}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{-45}{\radius}}%
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    pics/PINH/.style n args={1}{
        code = {
            \message{PINH params: #1}
            \foreach \s [count=\i] in {#1} {
                \message{count: \i,\s}
                \node[draw,cross,minimum size=0.5cm,label={above:\s},xshift={\i*0.6cm}] (-\i) {};
            }
            \node[fit=(-1)(-\i),draw] () {};
}}}
\tikzset{
    pics/PINV/.style n args={2}{
        code = {
            \message{PINV params: #1,#2}
            \foreach \s [count=\i] in {#2} {
                \node[draw,cross,minimum size=0.5cm,label={left:\s},yshift={-\i*0.6cm}] (-\i) {};
            }
            \node[fit=(-1)(-\i),draw] () {};
}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (A) {PINH={A,B,C,D}};
    \message{test here:}
    \pic (B) [below=1em of A.south west] {PINV={}{E,F,G,H}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can see, PINH and PINV actually only use 1 argument, but PINH only parsed the first letter A and PINV parsed all letters E,F,G,H.

That means the first argument actually handled differently in pics. Maybe my understand is wrong!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `n args={1}` is not officially supported, and indeed, if you leave it out, you get

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,fit,calc}  
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{cross}{
    \inheritsavedanchors[from=circle]
    \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]
    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
    \foreach \i in {center,north,south,east,west} {
        \inheritanchor[from=circle]{\i}
    }
    \backgroundpath{
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\radius}%
    }
    \foregroundpath{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{-135}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{45}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointpolar{135}{\radius}}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{-45}{\radius}}%
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    pics/PINH/.style={
        code = {
            \message{PINH params: #1}
            \foreach \s [count=\i] in {#1} {
                \message{count: \i,\s}
                \node[draw,cross,minimum size=0.5cm,label={above:\s},xshift={\i*0.6cm}] (-\i) {};
            }
            \node[fit=(-1)(-\i),draw] () {};
}}}
\tikzset{
    pics/PINV/.style n args={2}{
        code = {
            \message{PINV params: #1,#2}
            \foreach \s [count=\i] in {#2} {
                \node[draw,cross,minimum size=0.5cm,label={left:\s},yshift={-\i*0.6cm}] (-\i) {};
            }
            \node[fit=(-1)(-\i),draw] () {};
}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (A) {PINH={A,B,C,D}};
    \message{test here:}
    \pic (B) [below=1em of A.south west] {PINV={}{E,F,G,H}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just modify original code so just try down counter to 1. I really don't know 1 actually is special! :-)  Thanks!